# How to add a Drop-down Control that Filters Data Dynamically?

Tags: looker-studio

In Excel we have 3 dropdown menus to select by `city`, `branch` - the charts on the right are redrawn according to selected `city`:

[image]

When migrating to Google Data Studio, it seems it has limited functionality to do the same thing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individual [Drop-down lists](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144#drop-down-list-and-fixed-size-lists) can be used to view subsets of the data (using one for `city` another for `branch`, etc). Selecting items in one [Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) will automatically filter values in the other [Control(s)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/21cbceef-99e0-4bcc-a7b3-8511b115eba9) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BV0AS7kT4nyXdc2zOhSH9RJOEmD79afdSwyNDQKtGIY/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]